# Problems with Grape params

Tags: ruby, parameters, ruby-grape

```
    requires :foo, type: Hash do
      requires :bar, type: String
      requires :baz, type: String
    end
```

The above code works fine with cURL. Whereas it throws validation error while trying to run rspec. Remove 'type: Hash' does not work with cURL but works with rspec.

```
    {"error":"foo is invalid, foo[bar] is invalid"}
```

Which is the correct way of grouping params in Grape?

**Updated:**

without type: Hash

cURL:

```
   curl -X POST -d '{"foo":{"bar":"bar", "baz":"baz"}}' \
         'http://localhost:5000/test' \
         -v
```

returns

```
   {"error":"foo is invalid"}
```

Trying to run **rspec** with type :Hash returns the Argument error

```
   lib/grape/validations.rb:158:in `new_scope': ArgumentError (ArgumentError)
```

Comment: Can you show your curl command and rspec test? If type `Hash` is omitted, grape assumes an Array (of hashes).

Comment: More information on your test is required. How are you setting up the server and calling the route within rspec? Are you using a library e.g. `rack-test`?

Comment: The curl will only work for type `Hash` and not for the `Array`. So how do you do the rspec?

Comment: Actually it works fine when upgrading to Grape 0.8.0v. More info https://github.com/intridea/grape/issues/688.

Comment: Thanks, I was running trying to just run 'rspec'. I am using Grape inside Rails engine.

Comment: Mmm just running `rspec` executes some tests no? So which test fails? From the link I think you were running the grape test-suite? And it failed??? *confused* From what we see it seems logical that when you define the group as `Hash` and do the curl, and then remove the `Hash` (which makes it an array), that the same curl statement would no longer work. If you cannot show the rspec it is hard to tell, but I am assuming it only works for Array and not hash, right? So both ways are correct, but you have to specify your params differently for it.